# Create sections based on date

Tags: reactjs

I have an array and have to create sections based on date. So that all the elements in an array containing one date should come up in one section. Here `flags` is a sorted array which contains timestamp[image: The end result should look like this]
Here is what I got so far:

```
<Row gutter={20}>
{flags.map((flag, i) => {
    return 
      <div>
      <Row gutter={20}>
      {flags.map((flag, i) => {
        return(
          <div>
           {flags[i-1] && (moment(flags[i].timestamp).format('DD')!== moment(flags[i-1].timestamp).format('DD')) ? <Timestamp> {moment(flags[i].timestamp).format('DD')}</Timestamp> : <div><FlagComponent loading={loading} flag={flag} /> </div> }
        </div>
       ); })
      }
      </Row>
    </div>
}
</Row>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution so felt like sharing it here, basically I created groups which all have same timestamp and just map through it:

```
const groups = flags.reduce((groups, flag) => {
    const flagDate = flag.timestamp
    if (!groups) {
      groups= [];
    }
    groups.push(flag);
    return groups;
  }, {});

  const groupArrays = Object.keys(groups).map(flagDate => {
    return {
      flagDate,
      flags: groups[flagDate]
    };
  });
```

so `groupArrays` contains array of elements of one particular date

Comment: can you please share this working program on codesandbox. I am developing an application in react and facing the same problem of rendering data based on the date. It will be very helpful if you can share this.